# How do I create objects in a for loop while changing the object name in each iteration in Java?

Tags: java, oop

I have a for loop for iterating over a vector, in which I need to create an object each time a condition proves true, it's as follows,

```
 for(String element : myVector){
 if(conditon==true) {
   Object objectName = new Object(element) ;
 }
 .....
 ....
```

For each time I need to change the object name, for which I tried a silly solution

```
 String objectName = "object" + an auto incrementing integer
```

But my compiler does not recognize it as a previously declared string and gives an error stating such a variable is already created

Is there a way to fix this problem or a more efficient method to do my task?

Comment: You don't; you store each of the newly-made objects into some kind of container, as opposed to trying to make a new variable for each.  For example, the vector you are getting your strings from is such a container.

Comment: `an auto incrementing integer` is not valid Java. What did you *actually* do in your code? We cannot tell what's wrong with it if you don't show the actual code.

Comment: `For` and `If` also aren't valid

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there are a few syntax errors:

`For` should be `for`, `If` should be `if` and `string` should be `String`.

You are storing every newly-created object into the same reference variable.
To keep all created objects you have to save/store them into a list (or another appropriate data-structure).

```
List<Object> myList = new ArrayList<>(); //In this list we will store all the created objects
for (String element : myVector) {
     if (condition==true) {
         myList.add(new Object(element));
     }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the syntax errors i was in a rush and typed a dummy code on my phone since i just wanted get the idea through, but your answer gave the solution i was looking for thanks!